# Import from one workbook into a master workbook with different source cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Beginner in google sheets. I'm trying to transfer data from one workbook into one master workbook in google sheets. I need it to be in app script as it's going to be embedded into a button. Unfortunately the code that i have come up with did not go as planned.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKJVt.png)

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGenV.png)

Here is my code

```
    function myFunction() {


 //get the date from current Spreadsheet
 // C3 J6 F10-F14
 var sourcesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var analyst = sourcesheet.getRange('C3');
 var analystVal = analyst.getValues();

 var finalScore= sourcesheet.getRange('J6');
 var finalScoreVal = finalScore.getValues();

 var communication= sourcesheet.getRange('F10');
 var communicationVal = communication.getValues();

 var criteria1= sourcesheet.getRange('F11');
 var criteria1Val = criteria1.getValues();

 var criteria2= sourcesheet.getRange('F12');
 var criteria2Val = criteria2.getValues();

 var criteria3= sourcesheet.getRange('F13');
 var criteria3Val = criteria3.getValues();

 var criteria4= sourcesheet.getRange('F14');
 var criteria4Val = criteria4.getValues();

 //Open new Spreadsheet & paste the data
  var megaform = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1H0v-rFqL4EKvixi5oTVJ65nTxnEzHJlPmu5SUrkgJp4");
  Logger.log(megaform.getLastRow());
  megaform.getActiveSheet().getRange(megaform.getLastRow()+1, 3).setValues(analystVal);
  megaform.getActiveSheet().getRange(megaform.getLastRow()+1, 4).setValues(finalScoreVal);
  megaform.getActiveSheet().getRange(megaform.getLastRow()+1, 5).setValues(communicationVal);
  megaform.getActiveSheet().getRange(megaform.getLastRow()+1, 6).setValues(criteria1Val);
  megaform.getActiveSheet().getRange(megaform.getLastRow()+1, 7).setValues(criteria2Val);
  megaform.getActiveSheet().getRange(megaform.getLastRow()+1, 8).setValues(criteria3Val);
  megaform.getActiveSheet().getRange(megaform.getLastRow()+1, 9).setValues(criteria4Val);

}
```

Basically once this works, i plan to expand it into multiple sheets from multiple workbooks into the master workbook. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: getValues() returns an array not a value. I would get all of the values at one time and then select them with their indices. Perhaps pass them to anther function as an object.

Comment: Hi cooper, how would you go about that way?

Comment: Take a look at getDataRange() and getValues().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to put the desired data into an array rather than going with name value pairs in an object.  I also choose to append the data as a new row in the Master Spreadsheet. You can modify as desired.

```
function getMyData() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var dtA=[vA[2][2],vA[5][9],vA[9][5],vA[10][5],vA[11][5],vA[12][5],vA[13][5]];// C3 J6 F10-F14
  var dsA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<dtA.length;i++){
    dsA.push(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dtA[i]),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"E MM dd, yyyy"));
  }
  appendToMasterData(dsA);
}

function appendToMasterData(dA){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1auR3L1hTLw_P0fSJ8MJ470nYr-rVfAxvCUCLcW9Nl20');
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.appendRow(dA)

}
```

Source Sheet:

[image]

Your data was highlighted in light green and they are all dates.

Master Sheet:

[image]